# Update the coordinate of fabric js object on resize and skewing

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I tried to resize the fabric js object(rect),its width and height doesn't get updated.can any one give solution to it.

Comment: Please give us a [mcve] of your code. Without any code, it will be next to impossible for us to help you. Please also explain what you have tried so far to solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height and width proportionally using calculation of scalex, scaleY,height and width. First select your rectangle object.

In my project I used below code to change rectangle height

```
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
var new_height = 100;
var w = obj.getWidth() * obj.getScaleX();
var h = parseFloat(new_height) * obj.getScaleY();
obj.setHeight(h);
obj.setWidth(w);
obj.setScaleX(1);
obj.setScaleY(1);
obj.setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();
```

Same as you can change width of rectangle using below code

```
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
var new_width = 100;
var w = parseFloat(new_width) * obj.getScaleX();
var h = obj.getHeight() * obj.getScaleY();
obj.setHeight(h);
obj.setWidth(w);
obj.setScaleX(1);
obj.setScaleY(1);
obj.setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();
```